# Minimum circumference of a rotating spacecraft with artificial gravity

Tags: spaceships, artificial-gravity

In a rotating spacecraft that can generate artificial gravity similar to Earth’s, what would be the minimum circumference of the rotating system that would allow humans to comfortably live and work inside it, without significantly experiencing adverse effects such as motion sickness or Coriolis force?

The main living space would be along that circumference, although there may also be inner concentric layers where some Coriolis effect is tolerated.

Comment: Are the inhabitants allowed to acclimate, or does it need to be immediately usable to guests? That makes a big difference.

Comment: In addition to the duplicate provided, https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10597 and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/221300 have some useful answers that may help you. This is a fairly common topic on Worldbuilding and people have come at it from a variety of angles in the past.